# is it safe to use meta http-equiv=refresh in the body rather than the head tag as an alternative to php redirect?

Tags: php

on my web app when log off is selected i destroy all sessions then print this into the html

```
print "<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0'>";
```

rather than use the php header redirect since its all being done in the body and i have many includes going around. i thought that meta tag wouldnt work anywhere else other than header and thought i should give it a try and it worked! but now what im thinking is , is this method ok to use as an alternative to the php header redirect? i really hate how the php redirect was created, the fact that it need to not have any spaces or content before it for it to actually work.

let me know what you think. thanks

fyi this is how the log of is written.

the url will has a param like this:   the-page?action=logoff
then this is written in the header.php page that is included in every page

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "logoff")
{
    session_destroy();
    print "<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0'>";
}
```

Comment: Wait, what is wrong with the `header("Location: ")` redirect again?

Comment: Seems like some refactoring is in order.

Comment: @NullUserException I think he dislikes seeing the error *Cannot modify header information - headers already sent*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably easy to solve your problem using [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

Just `ob_start()` at the top of your script (or in some config.php file, or something), and you'll have no problems using header() regardless of what output functions you use before the need to redirect.